# Subindex a list of lists into block matrices X = [ [A, B], [C, D]]

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Let

```
X = [[2,3, 5, 6], 
     [4,5, 9, 10], 
     [6,1, 3, 9], 
     [3,7, 11, 12]]
```

How do I output the sub-matrices such that X = [ [A, B], [C, D]]?

```
    A = [[2, 3], 
         [4,5]]
    B = [[5,6], 
        [9, 10]] 
    C = [[6, 1], 
         [3,7]]
    D = [[3,9], 
        [11, 12]]
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Paddy This is trivial in Matlab. For Python, I've tried A = x[:2][:2][:2] but to no avail..

Comment: It's better to cast them as Numpy arrays. And then just need to give the start index as well.

Comment: @Antimony pretty sure X[:2] is the same as X[0:2]

Comment: @Antimony I don't want to use numpy

Comment: Well Numpy allows you to slice them like `X[0:2, 0:2]` but regular lists don't. What's the reason you don't want to use Numpy?
And yes, my bad, you can index them as `[:2]` as well.

Comment: @Antimony seems unnecessary for such a simple task

Comment: A = [row[0:2] for row in X[0:2]  First splice X to get the right rows, then splice the rows to get the right columns.  They both happen to go from 0 to 2 in the case of A, and they both happen to be the same, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: @KennyOstrom So the solution is non-trivial?

Comment: Honestly, if you want functionality similar to MATLAB, especially slicing 2D arrays, Numpy is the way to go in Python. MATLAB was built especially for things like vector algebra, but Python wasn't.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650538/sub-matrix-of-a-list-of-lists-without-numpy

Comment: Well, it's still trivial. But I don't know how you want to break up, e.g. a 5x7 matrix. Are you going to pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without using numpy.

```
A = [X[i][:2] for i in range(2)]
B = [X[i][2:] for i in range(2)]
C = [X[i][:2] for i in range(2,4)]
D = [X[i][2:] for i in range(2,4)]

>>> A
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> B
[[5, 6], [9, 10]]
>>> C
[[6, 1], [3, 7]]
>>> D
[[3, 9], [11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without numpy you can do it like this....

```
X = [[2,3, 5, 6], 
         [4,5, 9, 10], 
         [6,1, 3, 9], 
         [3,7, 11, 12]]

for i in X:
   print([i[ :len(i)//2],i[len(i)//2:]])
```

Comment: You have a syntax error -- an extra parenthesis. Also, the output is `[[5, 6], [2, 3]]` for A, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @rassar good catch, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, assuming the X is always a 4X4 Matrix:

```
X = [[2,3, 5, 6], 
 [4,5, 9, 10], 
 [6,1, 3, 9], 
 [3,7, 11, 12]]

new_matrix = [[X[i][:2], X[i+1][:2]] for i in range(0, len(X), 2)]
new_matrix.extend([[X[i][2:], X[i+1][2:]] for i in range(0, len(X), 2)]) 
print(new_matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using Numpy would look like this:

```
A = X[0:2, 0:2]
B = X[0:2, 2:4]
C = X[2:4, 0:2]
D = X[2:4, 2:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first sub-matrix you can use

```
A = [row[:2] for row in X[:2]]
```

(and similarly for the others)

Answer (score 1):

One liner version, though its a bit less readable

```
>>> (A,B),(C,D)= [([X[i][:2],X[i+1][:2]],[X[i][2:],X[i+1][2:]]) for i in range(0,len(X),2)]
>>>
>>? A
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>? B
[[5, 6], [9, 10]]
>>? C
[[6, 1], [3, 7]]
>>? D
[[3, 9], [11, 12]]
>>?
```