# Find the submatrix of a matrix without using numpy or zip

Tags: python

I am trying to find a method to find the submatrix of an array X where the user provides an input i and j like so:

```
def submatrix(X, i, j):
```

The expected output should be the matrix X without row i and column j.

Example :

```
X = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

submatrix(X, 1, 1)

```
    [[1, 3],
     [7, 9]]
```

I have tried to solve it on my own but obviously have not managed to do it and dont know where to begin. Hence asking for help.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Have you tried making a plan on paper? Any idea of where to start?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Show us your best attempts, things that can remove in each direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sub matrix of a list of lists (without numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650538/sub-matrix-of-a-list-of-lists-without-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

### Using `for loop`:

```
X = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

def submatrix(X, i, j):
    X=X[:]
    del(X[i]) # delete the row
    for n in range(len(X)):
        del(X[n][j])  # delete the column elements of the rows
    return X

X_new = submatrix(X, 1, 1)
[[1, 3], [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
def submatrix(X, i, j):
    return [[elem for x, elem in enumerate(row) if x != i]
            for y, row in enumerate(X) if y != j]

X = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

print(submatrix(X, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def submatrix(x, i, j):
    matrix = []
    for row in x[:i] + x[i+1:]:
        matrix.append(row[:j] + row[j+1:])
    return matrix
```

Examples

```
>>> submatrix([[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]], 1, 1)
[[1, 3],
 [7, 9]]

>>> submatrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
               [5, 6, 7, 8],
               [2, 4, 5, 9],
               [9, 6, 4, 3]], 2, 1)
[[1, 3, 4],
 [5, 7, 8],
 [9, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
First you should remove the row and then iterate through all row rows to remove the column index of the nested list. Like this

```
def submatrix(X, i, j):
    del X[i]
    for k in range(len(X)):
        del X[k][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work too:

```
def submatrix(X, i, j):
    X = X[:i] + X[i+1:] if i!= len(X) else X[:-1]
    X = [i[:j] + i[j+1:] if j!= len(X[0]) else i[:-1] for i in X]
    return X
```